# Implementing Google Chart API with ASP.NET MVC Database First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, google-api

I am trying to use google charts api to present data from my database. I am using the following tutorial: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-google-charts-api-integration/

I've noticed in the controller, that they load data in using a txt file.`string srcFilePath = "Content/files/SalesOrderDetail.txt";` Would there be a way to load the data in using entity framework and how would I do it?

I am new to mvc and using an api so I'm very unsure on how to achieve this.

I used database first for my project.

Controller:

```
using HolidayTracker.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Graphs.Controllers
{
 public class MetricsController : Controller
{
    #region Index method

    /// <summary>  
    /// GET: Home/Index method.  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <returns>Returns - index view page</returns>   
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Info.  
        return this.View();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Get data method.

    /// <summary>  
    /// GET: /Home/GetData  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <returns>Return data</returns>  
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        // Initialization.  
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

        try
        {
            // Loading.  
            List<Employee> data = this.LoadData();

            // Setting.  
            var graphData = data.GroupBy(p => new
            {
                p.FullName,
                p.HoursTaken,
                p.SickLeaveTaken
            })
                                .Select(g => new
                                {
                                    g.Key.FullName,
                                    g.Key.HoursTaken,
                                    g.Key.SickLeaveTaken
                                }).OrderByDescending(q => q.FullName).ToList();

            // Top 10  
            graphData = graphData.Take(10).Select(p => p).ToList();

            // Loading drop down lists.  
            result = this.Json(graphData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Info  
            Console.Write(ex);
        }

        // Return info.  
        return result;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Helpers

    #region Load Data

    /// <summary>  
    /// Load data method.  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <returns>Returns - Data</returns>  
    private List<Employee> LoadData()
    {
        // Initialization.  
        List<Employee> lst = new List<Employee>();

        try
        {
            // Initialization.  
            string line = string.Empty;
            string srcFilePath = "Content/files/SalesOrderDetail.txt";
            var rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
            var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, srcFilePath);
            string filePath = new Uri(fullPath).LocalPath;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

            // Read file.  
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Initialization.  
                Employee infoObj = new Employee();
                string[] info = line.Split(',');

                // Setting.  
                infoObj.FullName = info[3].ToString();
                infoObj.HoursTaken = Convert.ToDecimal(info[0].ToString());
                infoObj.SickLeaveTaken = Convert.ToDecimal(info[0].ToString());


                // Adding.  
                lst.Add(infoObj);
            }

            // Closing.  
            sr.Dispose();
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // info.  
            Console.Write(ex);
        }

        // info.  
        return lst;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just create DB for this case.

First, you need create a table that mapping with SalesOrderDetail class

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesOrderDetail](
    [Sr] [int] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [OrderTrackNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Quantity] [int] NULL,
    [ProductName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SpecialOffer] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UnitPrice] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [UnitPriceDiscount] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
)
```

Second, you create a ADO.NET Entity Data Model. And add code to save data from file to Database. Change code in Load Data method

```
private List<SalesOrderDetail> LoadData()
        {
            // Initialization.
            List<SalesOrderDetail> lst = new List<SalesOrderDetail>();
            CustomerEntities ctx = new CustomerEntities();
            //lst = ctx.SalesOrderDetails.ToList();
            try
            {
                // Initialization.
                string line = string.Empty;
                string srcFilePath = "Content/files/SalesOrderDetail.txt";
                var rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, srcFilePath);
                string filePath = new Uri(fullPath).LocalPath;
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

                // Read file.
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    // Initialization.
                    SalesOrderDetail infoObj = new SalesOrderDetail();
                    string[] info = line.Split(',');

                    // Setting.
                    infoObj.Sr = Convert.ToInt32(info[0].ToString());
                    infoObj.OrderTrackNumber = info[1].ToString();
                    infoObj.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(info[2].ToString());
                    infoObj.ProductName = info[3].ToString();
                    infoObj.SpecialOffer = info[4].ToString();
                    infoObj.UnitPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(info[5].ToString());
                    infoObj.UnitPriceDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(info[6].ToString());

                    // Adding.
                    lst.Add(infoObj);
                    ctx.SalesOrderDetails.Add(infoObj);

                }

                ctx.SaveChanges();

                // Closing.
                sr.Dispose();
                sr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // info.
                Console.Write(ex);
            }

            // info.
            return lst;
        }
```

After first running, data from text file inserted to DB, you comment out code to get data from file and insert line of code `lst = ctx.SalesOrderDetails.ToList();` to read from DB.

```
private List<SalesOrderDetail> LoadData()
        {
            // Initialization.
            List<SalesOrderDetail> lst = new List<SalesOrderDetail>();
            CustomerEntities ctx = new CustomerEntities();
            lst = ctx.SalesOrderDetails.ToList();
            try
            {
                // Initialization.
                //string line = string.Empty;
                //string srcFilePath = "Content/files/SalesOrderDetail.txt";
                //var rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
                //var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, srcFilePath);
                //string filePath = new Uri(fullPath).LocalPath;
                //StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

                //// Read file.
                //while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                //{
                //    // Initialization.
                //    SalesOrderDetail infoObj = new SalesOrderDetail();
                //    string[] info = line.Split(',');

                //    // Setting.
                //    infoObj.Sr = Convert.ToInt32(info[0].ToString());
                //    infoObj.OrderTrackNumber = info[1].ToString();
                //    infoObj.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(info[2].ToString());
                //    infoObj.ProductName = info[3].ToString();
                //    infoObj.SpecialOffer = info[4].ToString();
                //    infoObj.UnitPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(info[5].ToString());
                //    infoObj.UnitPriceDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(info[6].ToString());

                //    // Adding.
                //    lst.Add(infoObj);
                //    ctx.SalesOrderDetails.Add(infoObj);

                //}

                //ctx.SaveChanges();

                // Closing.
                //sr.Dispose();
                //sr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // info.
                Console.Write(ex);
            }

            // info.
            return lst;
        }
```

You can download source code at
https://github.com/viethien/MVC5GoogleGraph

Comment: So I'm alittle confused with the txt file. Is it there for data purposes or is it used to take data from the database?

Comment: I used that text file to insert into DB for testing, you can add more data to database

Comment: Okay, cool! So if I had data in my db already, there would be no need for it? So my  `LoadData()` method would look like the second part with the commented out code you posted.

Comment: only need call lst = ctx.SalesOrderDetails.ToList(); and comment out code for reading file

Comment: It did'nt seem to work. I used break points and it seem `var graphData` has datacount 0 but I definitely have data in the db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189586/discussion-between-conor8630-and-hien-nguyen).